# SVN to CVS migration with meta-data

Tags: svn, cvs

Is there a tool or script  that can migrate from SVN to CVS and also preserving meta-data and branches?
I have tried svn2cc script but its doing from CVS to SVN

Comment: we are working on a migration from git to cc this is a management choice 
i can not find a direct way
what i have reached full migration from git to svn and from cvs to cc

couldnt find a way for git to cvs or cvs to cc

so my only way now is git - svn and svn - cvs later cvs to cc

thanks

Comment: I would suggest that you post a new question now how to migrate from git to cc, I'm sure there are better ways than git -> svn -> cvs -> cc.

Comment: I did , didn't find a way , only some bridge that can not get old data only new commits
even IBM didnt know the answer

Comment: "this is a management choice" Perhaps you should inform management that what is being proposed is technically quite difficult (maybe impossible?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There won't be a tool to do this so your only solution is probably to use the generic export  "git-fast-export" to produce a clean conversion file.

However, if you're just going to run a command for every item in the file you might consider  using "git filter-branch"

This command allows you to checkout every commit from a git repository in sequence and run a script for that commit. Normally this is used to do nasty modifications on the git repository, but there's nothing that says your script can't create a checkin to another VCS instead.

Everything that git knows about a commit is available and can be replicated.

The basic "no-op" command is:

$ git filter-branch  --commit-filter 'git commit-tree "$@"' -- --all

DON'T go via CVS by the way; you will probably lose information as to which files are changed in a commit and will definite lose one of 'COMMIT_DATE' or 'AUTHOR_DATE'.